# If Q* can break encryption would that prove P=NP?

Tags: np, artificial-intelligence, cryptography

At [12:11 in this video](https://youtu.be/3d0kk88IE8c?t=729) the creator talks about unverified rumors the **Q* algorithm** can break AES-192 encryption. If this is true, would this mean **P = NP**?

Comment: I think that for any interpretation of this question, the answer is no.

Comment: @PålGD even if this was for RSA instead of AES?

Comment: Finding $k \in \{0,1\}^{128}$ given $\operatorname{AES}_k(0)$ takes $O(1)$ time because the input size $n$ is a constant, but that fact implies nothing about its feasibility in practice.

Comment: Yes, any kind of "break" for a fixed-size AES or RSA or whatever takes constant time. The constant may be extremely large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to show how being able to break AES-192 encryption would make it possible to solve some NP-complete problem. There would have to be an algorithm like this:

“Given is an instance P of an NP-complete problem. Given P we construct one or more instances of AES-192 encryption, break them all, and use the result to solve the instance P”.

For “breaking encryption” there is another problem: We consider encryption to be broken if a significant number of encryptions can be broken, not all. So even if being able to break *all* instances of AES-192 could prove P=NP, breaking enough instances to consider AES-192 broken might not be enough.

Comment: Somewhat unfortunate choice of name for an instance.